# beyond standardization of data

Tags: standardization

Suppose that there are two attributes, x1 and x2, in the dataset. Further suppose that the values of x1 are 100, 105, 110 and the values of x2 are 1000, 1005, 1010. Now, if I standardize these attributes by subtracting mean and then dividing by standard deviation I will obtain the same values for x1 and x2. The spread of the data is the same for both attributes. However, since the values of x2 are larger than x1 the differences in x2 are less important compared to the differences in x1. Standardization seems to lose this difference. What can I do?
Thanks

Comment: What are you using these features for?

Comment: Do you have to standardise them? You don't explain why you're doing it.

Comment: I don't have  particular application. This is a general question. I know that it is a common practice to standardize the data before applying a machine learning algorithm. However, this might lead to loosing some information.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand what you are trying to do. In your example, x2 is a shifted version of x1. All sensible form of centering should make x1 indistinguishable from x2.

Comment: @user603 take x3 whose values are 5, 10, 15. This is also a shifted version of the others. What I mean is the differences in x3 are more important than the differences in x1 and x2.

Comment: Sanyo Min - you are completely right.  It is up to the analyst to decide whether the standard deviation is meaningful or not. Many statistical algorithms will give different results depending on whether you standardise. eg PCA, L1/L2 regularisation of linear regression.  Gradient descent as used by eg neural networks benefit from standardisation.